# Design question

Tags: database-design

I want to implement an extension to my following table

Object table == building in generall

```
+--------+-----------+------+--------------+-----------+-------+------+
| obj_id | obj_ident | name | FKsupervisor | FKAddress | Phone | Fax  |
+--------+-----------+------+--------------+-----------+-------+------+
|      1 | ABC-123   | Test |            1 |         1 |  0000 | 0000 |
+--------+-----------+------+--------------+-----------+-------+------+
```

The object(building) need's to have also some extra field's like electrical review/sctructural review and several other types. On top of that they can be a yearly based review or 5 years review. The question is how to make a quite simple and scalable schema for the table that will keep the reviews. Reviews should cosist of the following fields as base :: [ each building can have multiple reviews ]

```
* added(datetime), a scan(pdf<varchar> to patch), 
* obviously the link to object(building), 
* possible the type of valid review lenght i.e 1 year/5 years (datetime) [ expire date ]
```

Looking forward for some ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider adding 2 more tables. "Reviews" would contain the review columns itself, DateAdded, ExpiryDate etc, and a ReviewID. Then I'd have a second (junction) table ObjectReview which links buildings to Reviews, and would contain obj_id and ReviewID to tie reviews to buildings.

One important point - it's not clear from your question - but you call one column a scan ("pdf"), I would most strongly advise against storing PDFs or other BLOBs in a database. Leave them in the filesystem where they belong and store only a pointer to that file in the database. I hope that's what you meant!

Comment: What I meant with a pdf is that I only store the path to the file in a var_dump, is that bad too? Well your answer was what I would try to implement also, good that I have a confirmation on that one

Comment: No that's not bad, storing the path in the table is fine.